# SVN server authentication on Mac - users are not recognized

Tags: svn, authentication, mac, authorization

We have a anomaly here, trying to set up SVN authentication. Here is apache configuration:

```
<Location /repo_main>
 DAV svn
 SVNPath /svn/repo_main
 AuthType Basic
 AuthName "svn"
 AuthzSVNAccessFile /svn/repo_main/conf/authz
 Require valid-user
 <Limit GET HEAD OPTIONS CONNECT POST PROPFIND PUT DELETE PROPPATCH MKCOL COPY MOVE LOCK UNLOCK>
    Require group  svn
</Limit>
```

And here is authz file content:

```
[/]
* = 
[repo_main:/projects/sample_project]
user1 = rw
```

When we trying to access with user1 to specified directory - we have permission error. When setting access to everyone:

> [/] * = rw

everything works fine. So, it looks like it doesn't recognize the user some how... 
And, the anomaly consist of following thing - there is one user exists that actually works as expected!!!! and nothing special in this user - he is not an admin. What is happening???

It looks like hard nut, but please post anything that may help (your ideas). Thank You all for help!!!!

Comment: Have you taken a look into apache log? I assume the missing </Location> tags is just a typo?

Comment: yes, </Location> is a typo, sorry for confusion. It actually runs fine - the problem is authentication

Comment: Have you taken a look into the apache logs?

Comment: no, I didn't. actually, I just confused - where is these users should be specified at all??? "user1" - should I add this user in the "System Preferences"->"Accounts"? I have Mac Mini server

Comment: Just checked apache logs, it's saying "Access denied"